# Help me find a tutorial to dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

What I've got is a compatible PC with both systems ,Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 ,I've Windows 7 already installed ,now I want to install Ubuntu, and be able to choose which one I want to boot when I power my computer on.

First time I tried it ,I didn't watch any tutorial ,installed Ubuntu on another partition from Windows 7 (D) ,and got that partition deleted ,lost many files but I just want to have Ubuntu and have some experience with it !

Any help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a How to  from Ubuntu --> [Ubuntu Installation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)

Helpful links:

[How to burn a DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)

[How to create a bootable USB-Stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

[Install Ubuntu with with the Windows installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I had such wish before so I selected an easier way. It's installing a virtual machine (e.g., WMware workstation) and then install any other OSs (like, ubuntu) on it.
hope it helps.
This link also will be helpful https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: note that this method has its drawbacks in terms of performance and persistency.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start the installation, create a separate disk partition in Windows. Insert your bootable disc/USB device. Follow the instructions. When you see the disk chooser, select your newly created disk. Select the `Change` option from below. Format it to `ext4` and select mount point `/`. Press okay. Below, you'll see option for bootloader device. Click on it and choose the `topmost` option (It'll have some information about your HDD i.e. its size, manufacturer etc). Click continue when you are asked for `swap partition` option. If you do want to create a `swap partition` you'll have to create another partition. You won't need it in normal use anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Dual Boot Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 7 - on YouTube

http://youtu.be/xK8X7_tYWmA

I found the video above to be very helpful.

You may also want to consider partitioning your hard drive as described below, which will allow you to access data files from both Windows and Ubuntu. I suggest using Windows Disk Manager to do this if you are more familiar with Windows. GParted, the disk management tool in Ubuntu, can also accomplish it -- but make sure the partition you create is NTFS format. (Windows can only use NTFS; Linux can "see" both Linux partitions and NTFS, but Windows can't)

One partition for Windows recovery and system files

One partition for Windows OS and related files
(These are probably already in place since you have Windows installed)

From the remaining space, create a partition you can use for storage of docs, pictures, videos, etc. If you format this in NTFS, both Win7 and Ubuntu will be able to access the files.

Then go ahead and install Ubuntu. It will ask you whether you want to create a new partition in order to place Ubuntu into it. And it will create its own swap file if you choose the regular installation as opposed to the advanced. The video I linked above shows how to do the advanced installation, which is really pretty simple if you follow along carefully.

Good luck and enjoy Ubuntu - my installation has been working very well so far.